Proving that the limit of $\frac{e^{(tA_\lambda)}u - u}{t}$ as $t\downarrow 0$ exists in a Banach space $X$ for every $u\in X$
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A$ a closed densely defined (note: not necessarily bounded) linear operator on $X$ and let $\lambda > 0$. Define
$$A_\lambda := -\lambda I + \lambda^2 R_\lambda$$
for the resolvent operator $R_\lambda$ of $A$,
$$R_\lambda := (\lambda I - A)^{-1}$$
Define also
$$S_\lambda(t) := e^{tA_\lambda} = e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda^2 t)^k}{k!}R_\lambda^k$$
I am trying to verify that the limit of
$$\frac{S_\lambda(t)u - u}{t}$$
exists as $t\downarrow 0$ for every $u\in X$.
Currently I am stuck because I simply don't know how I should conclude that the limit exist. I might have seen a proof like this couple of years ago, and I have a vague memory  that this proof requires a quite specific trick to get right, when you are working with "bounded linear operator exponentials". Don't get me wrong, I would very much like to just conclude that $\frac{d}{dt}S(t) = A_\lambda S(t)$, but I haven't (at least yet) read any chain rule property for bounded linear operators, so that is out of the picture.
I appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

The derivative rule for the exponential of a matrix is proved it proposition 2.7 in here: https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/de/forschung/agfa/members/a_short_course_on_operator_semigroups-1.pdf It basically works the same for bounded linear operators. (Note that $A_\lambda$ is a bounded linear operator in this case)
